# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(x^2+1)}$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, sequence-of-function

> For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f_n:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $f_n(x)=\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(x^2+1)}$. Find the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$.

I know that for all $x>0$ we have that $$|f_n(x)| = \left| \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(x^2+1)} \right| \leq \frac{n\cdot (x/n)}{x(x^2+1)} = \frac{1}{x^2+1}.$$ I guess that $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is the function that we are looking for. However, I don't know how to prove it by using the definition of pointwise limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointwise limit $f$ of the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ you get by computing, for every $x>0$, the limit

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(x^2+1)}.$$

Notice that (substituting $h=\frac{1}{n}$) this is the same limit as

$$f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(xh)}{xh}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{x^2+1},$$

and, so as you can see, we get the same limit that you computed.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks!!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: I was going to do it, but I have to wait at least 3 minutes more.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help you!